# Odoo 11 How to override compute_all() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am developping a module to use a custom formula for the amount calculation method in invoices and sales orders.
The line amount formula should be : **nbJours * price_unit * quantity** instead of the default formula : **price_unit * quantity**

I added a custom field to **AccountInvoiceLine** class by inheriting it as following :

```
class AccountInvoiceLine(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.invoice.line"
# Nombre de jours de location
nombreJours = fields.Integer("Nombre de jours",default=1,required=True)

@api.multi
@api.depends('nombreJours','price_unit', 'discount', 'invoice_line_tax_ids', 'quantity', 'product_id', 'invoice_id.partner_id', 'invoice_id.currency_id', 'invoice_id.company_id', 'invoice_id.date_invoice', 'invoice_id.date')
def _compute_price(self):
    ...
    ...
    if self.invoice_line_tax_ids:
        taxes = self.invoice_line_tax_ids.compute_all(self.nombreJours, price, currency, self.quantity, product=self.product_id, partner=self.invoice_id.partner_id)

    # Calcul du sous-total de la ligne
    self.price_subtotal = price_subtotal_signed = taxes['total_excluded'] if taxes else self.quantity * price * self.nombreJours
    self.price_total = taxes['total_included'] if taxes else self.price_subtotal
    ...
    ...
```

And I also need to set the custom formula in the **AccountTax** class. I tried to override the compute_all() method :

```
# Modification du modèle de Taxes
class AccountTax(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.tax'

@api.multi
def compute_all(self, nbJrs=1, price_unit=1, currency=None, quantity=1.0, product=None, partner=None):
    ...
    ...
    if not base_values:
            odooAmount = price_unit * quantity
            customAmount = nbJrs * odooAmount
            total_excluded = total_included = base = round( customAmount , prec)
        else:
            total_excluded, total_included, base = base_values
    ...
    ...

    return {
        'taxes': sorted(taxes, key=lambda k: k['sequence']),
        'total_excluded': currency.round(total_excluded) if round_total else total_excluded,
        'total_included': currency.round(total_included) if round_total else total_included,
        'base': base,
    }
```

I've successfully updated my module, but when I try to add a product in a new invoice I get this error :

> ... ... ...
>   File "/OdooERP/Odoo 11.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 618, in _onchange_invoice_line_ids taxes_grouped = self.get_taxes_values()
>   File "/OdooERP/Odoo 11.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 889, in get_taxes_values taxes = line.invoice_line_tax_ids.compute_all(price_unit, self.currency_id, line.quantity, line.product_id, self.partner_id)['taxes']
>
> File "/OdooERP/Instances/xaymalab/addons/sunu_location_event/models/accountinvoice.py",line 82, in compute_all **odooAmount = price_unit * quantity**
>
> **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'res.currency' and 'product.product'**

When I remove "**nbJrs**" parameter in the definition, it works!
The values shift one parameter to the right.
Can anybody help me out regarding it?

Comment: I mean... the error is pretty simple,  you're trying to multiply something that doesn't support the operation.  Just add the following print statement before the error line to see what's going wrong: print("price_unit type %s value %s quantity type: %s value %s" % (type(price_unit), price_unit, type(quantity), quantity).  It's probably that when you remove the parameter from the function def your caller is assigning different values to the input variables (I guess). You can only multiply things that support it,  and by the looks of the code it seems like you're expecting numbers there.

Comment: Just one more thing outsite of my answer: It is just lucky the method call even worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**How I solved this :**
I was trying to override the compute_all() by adding a new parameter. It was the wrong way.
I updated the _compute_price() by adding a new variable "**rentalprice**" and passing it to compute_all():

```
def _compute_price(self):
    currency = self.invoice_id and self.invoice_id.currency_id or None
    price = self.price_unit * (1 - (self.discount or 0.0) / 100.0)
    # Prix unitaire d'un article pendant la durée totale de location:
    rentalprice = self.nombrejours * price
    taxes = False
    if self.invoice_line_tax_ids:
        taxes = self.invoice_line_tax_ids.compute_all(rentalprice, currency, self.quantity, product=self.product_id, partner=self.invoice_id.partner_id)
```

I removed the **AccountTax** inheritance code because I no longer need it, updated my module and now it's working.

Thanks to @CZoellner for helping me to better understand what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake on overriding `compute_all()` of `account.tax`. Seems you've added a new parameter `nbJrs`. The [original Method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/85f8e4761b9ad1d05ed787de4235fbbdfd33d7dd/addons/account/models/account.py#L897-L900):

```py
def compute_all(self, price_unit, currency=None,
    quantity=1.0, product=None, partner=None)
```

and yours:

```py
def compute_all(self, nbJrs=1, price_unit=1, currency=None,
    quantity=1.0, product=None, partner=None):
```

That just won't work this way. The error is: You're multiplying the value of `currency` with the value of `product`, because the values shift one parameter to the right.

Comment: Hi @CZoellner . Thank you for your response.
You're right. But there is something I can't understand : when I debug the code with PyCharm, I can see that calculations are well done.
What am I missing?
What is the right way of overriding compute_all() method?
Thank you.

Comment: **nbJrs** is a a custom field that I added. It represent a number of days.
I need to set the calculation of invoices/sales orders line amounts as following :    "nbJrs * price_unit * quantity" instead of the default formula : "price_unit * quantity"

Comment: And why do you need it as a parameter of a already existing method? Where is the value coming from? Maybe it's possible to get the value within the method, or you could use the context to get it into it. If it's a "global" value, just create a system parameter (`ir,config,parameter`) or company setting.

Comment: I updated my question for a better understanding.
There is Something I need to be sure : When I override a method, Can I add new parameters?

Comment: Depends on the method. In this case, and most cases in odoo: no.